# Create custom column in SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
ITEM    PICTURE    CATEGORY    STOCK
 1      Mickey     Shirt        3
 2      Mickey     Jacket       2
 3      Donald     Jacket       0
 4      Donald     Shirt        6
 5      Donald     Hoodie       1
 6      Mickey     Hoodie       3
 7      Goofy      Shirt        1
 8      Goofy      Hoodie       2
 9      Goofy      Jacket       3
```

The ITEM column is auto increment

I need an output like this:

```
PICTURE    HOODIE    JACKET    SHIRT
Donald       1         0         6
Goofy        2         3         1
Mickey       3         2         3
```

Any idea how I can produce that output? Thank you

Comment: You can use *conditional aggregation*. There are plenty of examples here in SO.

Comment: A better idea would be some simple application code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CASE` expression.

**Query**

```
select PICTURE,
sum(case CATEGORY when 'Hoodie' then STOCK else 0 end) as `HOODIE`,
sum(case CATEGORY when 'Jacket' then STOCK else 0 end) as `JACKET`,
sum(case CATEGORY when 'Shirt' then STOCK else 0 end) as `SHIRT`
from your_table_name
group by PICTURE;
```